# Access previously run shell command in single user mode

Tags: command-line, single-user

The shell which opens in Single User Mode on my Mac doesn‘t allow to just use „Cursor up“ to access the previous command.

How can easily do this without having to retype it?

Comment: Shell history should operate normally in single-user mode (although it won't use the history file from your normal account). What exactly are you trying to do, and how does the result differ from what you expect?

Answer (score 2):

The "classical" history commands described in the "HISTORY EXPANSION" section of `man bash` should work in single user mode:

- `history` lists the command history
- `!!` reexecutes the previous command
- `!!:p` prints the previous command without executing it
- `!n` reexecutes the nth command from the history
- `^string1^string2^` replaces `string1` by `string2` in the previous command and reexecutes it
- `!n:s^string1^string2^` does the same with the nth command (notice the extra `s` after the `:`)

This should make it easier to perform the usual shell tasks. For more complex modifications, please have a look at the mentioned section in the man page.